# how to make xmlhttprequest to ruby from html

Tags: php, android, ruby, cordova

I am making a Phone-Gap android application, I have a ruby library and i hope i can  implement it using an Xmlhttprequest.

Is there anyway to do so? since phonegap only supports html css and javascript.
ps: I have the library in both ruby and php but I haven't figured my way around it in php yet.

I just don't get these json_decode() php functions, so if any1 can explain these that'd be awesome.

I have tried searching for this on google, but all i get is xmlhttprequests from javascript to ruby on rails, and i dont think i can use rails in phonegap, can i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the server side application (written in Rails, PHP or whatever), a XMLHTTPRequest (or XHR for short) is nothing more than a  HTTP request. So just implement your controllers as usual. Rails accepts JSON formatted requests as well as application/x-www-form-urlencoded ones, and can be accessed quite intuitively with `params` without the need to manually parse it. If you want to send a JSON response, just `render :json => anything`.

Oh, I forgot it. To performantly parse and generate JSON, you'll need the gem [Oj](https://github.com/ohler55/oj)

### Rails example

Suppose the mobile client post the following data to `/songs`

```
{
  "song" : {
    "title": "Fly Me to the Moon",
    "artist": "Frank Sinatra"
  }
}
```

**songs_controller.rb**

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    params[:song]  #=> {"title" => "Fly Me to the Moon", "artist" => "Frank Sinatra"}
    @song = ...  # Model instance
    render json: @song
  end
end
```

### Sinatra example

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'oj'
require 'oj_mimic_json'

post '/songs' do
  params['song']  #=> {"title" => "Fly Me to the Moon", "artist" => "Frank Sinatra"}
  song = ...  # Model instance
  song.to_json
end
```

### Low level Rack example without middlewares

```
require 'oj'
require 'oj_mimic_json'

app = -> (env) {
  request = Rack::Request.new(env)
  params = Oj.load request.body
  [201, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}, [params['song']]]
}
Rack::Handler::WEBrick.run app
```

Comment: can u please give me an example ? and can i use ruby without any php or rails ? thank you

Comment: Thank you very much for the neat info, pretty cool stuff you got there, thanks